# readline in objective-c program throwing Mach-O Linker (Id) Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When I try to run the following code, xcode throws the following error.  What is causing this?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"What number would you like to count down by three from?");
        const char *countFrom = readline(NULL);
        NSString *result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:countFrom];
        NSLog(@"Counting down from %@", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_readline", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Where is `readline` implemented and how are you linking it?

Comment: Not sure, going through a book on Objective-C and just typing the examples into Xcode on the mac.

Comment: I wouldn't down-vote this.  There are various people asking this same question in various programming forums with no solid answers.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't down-vote.  In fact, I was wondering why when I saw it had happened.  (It's not a difficult question but it contained all the right information, unlike most of what I've read here this morning.)

Comment: No worries, I wasn't under the assumption it was you :)

Comment: This is a problem that I also encountered in The Big Nerd Range Guide for Objective C programming. Thank you for finding out the problem! I don't understand why this is a downvoted question.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out.  Had to go into the Link Binary With Libraries section in the Build Phases section of project settings and include libreadline.dylib.

Comment: I had success importing <stdio.h> rather than libreadline.dylib. The latter gave me an error stating there was no such library.